# How can I pass function that return component as props?

Tags: carousel, clojurescript, reagent

I need to create the carousel of my custom list item, and I already imported the one of carousel component lib (react-native-snap-carousel) to the project, but the carousel component needs props that return component which we need to render as carousel itemList.
 so I send the props like this

```
[carousel {:render-item (fn [] [my-custom-item]) 
               ...otherprops... }]
```

but it error with this messsage

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

how can I send the props as the function that return element ?

this is how to call the carousel component on the js

```
        <Carousel
          ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
          data={this.state.entries}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
          itemWidth={itemWidth}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Carousel component expects a react element or a string to be returned from render-item function. But you are returning plain reagent component.

You need to use reagent's [as-element](http://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/reagent.core.html#var-as-element) function convert a reagent component to react component:

```
[carousel {:render-item (fn [] (reagent/as-element [my-custom-item])) 
           ...otherprops... }]
```